# Clojure functions and gensym

Tags: clojure

I have a question about some code in Clojure's [compojure](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/) library.

```
(defn compile-route
  "Compile a route in the form (method path & body) into a function."
  [method route bindings body]
  `(make-route
    ~method ~(prepare-route route)
    (fn [request#]
      (let-request [~bindings request#] ~@body))))
```

I've only seen gensyms used in the context of macros, where they are used to prevent clashes between bindings used in the macro and bindings in the local scope.

I would think that since the above is a function and not a macro that it is immune to this. Therefore I am wondering what the rationale is for writing this function like a macro.

(In case you are wondering, I checked the commit history to see if this function was initially written as a macro. It was not.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although what you are seeing is a function and not a macro, it is a function which **generates Clojure code**. (It will almost certainly be called from within a macro.) AND, not only does it generate code, but it *inserts* code which is passed in as the `body` argument into the generated code. That is why it needs to gensym to avoid name clashes.

Although it's not a macro, it's doing the same kind of thing that macros do, and it uses gensym for the exact same reason.

Answer (score 5):

Gensyms (the `-#` notation at least) are used not in the context of macros, but in the context of backquote. In order to more or less ensure [macro hygiene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygienic_macro), symbols which do not resolve to globally qualified symbols cannot be used inside the backquote context. While this is not enforced and there is an escape hatch if you really want an unqualified symbol, it provides a sane default. For a more lengthy discussion of macro hygiene in Clojure see [this](http://xivilization.net/~marek/blog/2013/09/17/clojure-and-hygienic-macros/) blog post.